# How to EXTEND imported component styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I cannot extend my imported component. I was looking into styled components docs and find that in v4+ should works prop "as", but it doesnt.

**COMPONENT:**

```
    type Props = {
        padding: string,
        justify: string
    }

    const FlexContainer = styled.div<Props>`
        padding: ${props => props.padding};
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: ${props => props.justify};
    `

    export const Flexcontainer: React.FC<Props> = props =>{
        return (
        <FlexContainer padding={props.padding} justify={props.justify}>
            {props.children}
        </FlexContainer>


 )
}
```

**EXTENDED STYLE:**

```
import { Flexcontainer }  from '../../reusable/FlexContainer';

const FlexContainerExtended = styled.div`
  color: red;
`
```

**USE:**

```
<FlexContainerExtended
  padding={null}
  justify={"flex-start"}
  as={Flexcontainer}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the base component to the styled function to override it.

```
   type Props = {
        padding: string,
        justify: string
    }

    const FlexContainer = styled.div<Props>`
        padding: ${props => props.padding};
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: ${props => props.justify};
    `
    const FlexContainerExtended = styled(FlexContainer)`
       color: red;
    `

    export const Flexcontainer: React.FC<Props> = props =>{
        return (
        <FlexContainer padding={props.padding} justify={props.justify}>
            {props.children}
        </FlexContainer>
 )
}
// And use it like this
<FlexContainerExtended
  padding={null}
  justify={"flex-start"}/>
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but I need to make it inside component where I'm importing that Component.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with inside component?

Comment: I don't need to change styles inside FlexContainer, but outside. When i import component Flexcontainer in component xyz I need to override FlexContainer inside xyz.

Comment: you can't import FlexContainer in this scenario. it needs to be defined right there too

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a prop `className` to your `Flexcontainer` component like this:

```
export const Flexcontainer: React.FC<Props> = props =>{
    return (
      <FlexContainer className={props.className} padding={props.padding} justify={props.justify} >
        {props.children}
      </FlexContainer>
)}
```

To override styles, styled-components passes a className as props to the overrided component, it's why

Comment: This should be the correct solution if you want to extend an imported component style by using style component

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I leave here the solution I found for future visitors.

**Base component definition**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ContainerWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
`

export default function Container({ children, ...props }) {
  return (
    <ContainerWrapper {...props}>
      {children}
    </ContainerWrapper>
  )
}
```

**Extended component definition**

Obs.: note that the extended component is an `article`, while the base component is a `div`, and so far they have no relationship.

Also note that the base component (Container) has been imported but not yet used.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Container from '../../common/Container'

const HeroWrapper = styled.article`
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 74px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
`
```

**Invoking componentes**

Now, in the same file where I declared the extended component, I just call the base component, informing the name of the extended component in the `as` attribute.

```
export default function PostsWrapper() {
  return (
      <Container as={HeroWrapper}>
        {/* ...  */}
      </Container>
  )
}
```